# Why is the DIV with ID Form dropping below the adjacent DIVs?

Tags: html, css

I cannot correctly position the div `form` in my layout.

By looking at my div placement and css below, does anyone have an idea what I could be doing wrong?

```css
#floorplans {
  float: left;
  height: 165px;
  width: 203px;
  border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  position: relative;
  background: #FFFFFF url(https://lorempixel.com/320/170/) no-repeat;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

#development {
  float: left;
  height: 165px;
  width: 204px;
  border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  position: relative;
  background: #FFFFFF url(https://lorempixel.com/204/165/) no-repeat;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

#projects {
  background: #FFFFFF url(https://lorempixel.com/153/127/) no-repeat;
  height: 127px;
  width: 153px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 300px;
  color: #333333;
  padding-top: 25px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  clear: left;
}

#form {
  background: #990000 url(https://lorempixel.com/450/309/) no-repeat;
  float: left;
  height: 309px;
  width: 450px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="logo"></div>
  <div id="topnav"></div>
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
      <li id="last"><a href="#">link4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="gallery"></div>
  <div id="floorplans"></div>
  <div id="development"></div>
  <div id="projects"></div>
  <div id="form">
    <div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer"></div>
  </div>
```

You'll notice the div `form` is dropping down. What should I do to get things to line up? Should I rework the placement of the divs?

Comment: Agree w/ Nathan... can you ask an actual question, so that the rest of the SO community can benefit from this?

Comment: The question is: "Why is the DIV with ID Form dropping below the adjacent DIVs?"

Comment: @godleuf Also, it would be appreciated if you could put some time into creating a minimalist version of the faulty markup to post with the question.  With any luck, your link will stop working long before the question stops being useful to others.

Comment: Yes, this is a reasonable question, poorly phrased. The ideal here is that someone helps reword it, not that it gets buried into oblivion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form `div`'s top is in line with the top of the `div` that precedes it. The `clear:left;` on `#projects` moves `#projects` to the next line (good), along with the following content (bad). Try a negative top margin, or consider restructuring your HTML to put `#form` before `#projects`.

Adding the following should work:

```
#form {
    margin-top:-180px;
}
#projects {
    border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have two blocks (FLOORPLANS and DEVELOPMENT INFO) each with a border, they're now too wide to sit next to the form block. Test this by removing one or both borders and seeing if the form then pops back up there.

Note, negative margin often has issues in IE6, be sure and check any solution against that.